# Why do I get a 'Push Failed' error when I try to add products from DSers to my WooCommerce store?

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

DSers fails to push products to WooCommerce

Hello, I recently connected DSers to my new Woocommerce store, but everytime I try to push a product from Aliexpress to my store with DSers, I have the same error: "Push Failed".

The DSers support told me that the error is caused my the website responding with a 503 error while DSers is sending the product data via REST API.

To solve the problem I should do a test to add products to my WooCommerce via REST API. Then I could check the error log on my website to locate the reason why it doesn't accept the product data send via REST API.

Someone has an idea where the problem could come from because I don't know how to test the API?
I already changed the Upload Limit in wp-config.php and the memory limit and upload max filesize in the php.ini